# Could Bill Cipher be an avatar of Nyarlathotep?

Tags: character, gravity-falls

Bill Cipher, the big bad of [Gravity Falls](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1865718/) is a demon who loves spreading chaos and causing people to go insane. Nyarlathotep is a outer god from the works of Lovecraft who has a multitude of forms and avatars. He has similar shape changing, mind warping, and reality bending powers.

They both use trickery and seem to share similar goals, and Nyarlathotep often takes forms inspired by ancient Egyptian lore... when he is not rocking out as Mathew McConaughey to try to destroy some form of tower (allegedly). But Bill's pyramid form seems like a good thematic fit.

Is there any indication that the creator had the intention of Bill being connected to Nyarlathotep?

Comment: Good theory, although I always saw him as the Eye of Providence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Nyarlathotep but if he is physical to the world then no. Bill had to possess someone in order to have a physical form. Otherwise he only existed in the brain. So probably not. But Nyarlathotep does look like someone/thing that would exist in the nightmare realm along with keyhole, 8-ball, and kryptos.

Comment: Nyarlathotep has many (thousands of) different forms, physical and not. The Wiki article names 30ish of his forms, which include Randall Flagg from Stephen King's writings. Lovecraft was inspired to create the character from retellings of Nicola Tesla's public demonstrations.

Comment: @kleineg I would love a source link for that claim about Nicola Tesla.

Comment: @Tom I found a couple lines about Tesla's demonstrations being inspirations on the wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyarlathotep#Inspiration